# how to fix the le method

Tags: python, class

```
 {'a': [{'c','d'},  {'d'}        ],
 'b': [{'c','d'},  set()        ],
 'c': [set(),      {'a','b','d'}],
 'd': [{'a','c'},  {'a','b'}    ],
 'e': [set(),      set()        ]}

class Graph:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.edges = {}

    def __le__(self,right):
        for key, value in self.edges.items():
            if key not in  right.items() or value not in right.items():
                return False
        return True
```

Define the <= operator for comparing two Graphs. We define the meaning of g1 <= g2 as g1 is a subgraph of g2, which means that
all the nodes present in g1 are present in g2, and
all the edges prsent in g1 (origin node, destination node) are present in g2.
Trivially, for any Graph g, g <= g evaluates to True.

[image]

when I run my le function, it produces the following error:

```
g1.edges = {'a': [{'c'},{'d'}], 'b': [{'c','d'}, set()], 'c': [set(),{'a','b'}], 'd': [{'a'},{'b'}]}

g2.edges = {'a': [{'c'},{'d'}], 'b': [{'c','d'}, set()], 'c': [set(),{'a','b','d'}], 'd': [{'a','c'},{'b'}]}

g3.edges = {'a': [{'c','d'},{'d'}], 'b': [{'c','d'}, set()], 'c': [set(),{'a','b','d'}], 'd': [{'a','c'},{'a','b'}], 'e': [set(),set()]}


104 # Test <=
111 *Error: g1 <= g1 and g2 <= g2 and g3 <= g3 raised exception; unevaluated: True
112 *Error: g1 <= g2 raised exception; unevaluated: True
113 *Error: g2 <= g3 raised exception; unevaluated: True
115 *Error: g1 <= g2 raised exception; unevaluated: False
117 *Error: g2 <= g3 raised exception; unevaluated: False
```

can someone help me to fix my le function? thanks.

Comment: The structure of the graph is not clear. I would have expected that a node is associated with a list of neighbors or a set of neighbors. But what does `'b': [{'c','d'}, set()]` mean ??

Comment: @phynfo It's a directed graph, so, presumably, each node is associated with a pair of outgoing/incoming arcs. `'b': [{'c','d'}, set()]` means that `b` has an arc to `c` and `d`, and no incoming arcs, which matches the picture on the right.

Answer (score 0):

***right*** is **Graph** object, therefore it has no items attribute to call. It would fix your code bug,once you add edges, but it may not fix logic issue. Thank you.

```
def __le__(self,right):
   for key, value in self.edges.items():
      if key not in  right.edges.items() or value not in right.edges.items():
         return False
   return True
```